# Get current page url with Playwright Automation tool?

Tags: javascript, playwright

How can I retrieve the current URL of the page in Playwright?
Something similar to `browser.getCurrentUrl()` in Protractor?

Comment: I re-wrote the original question for clarity and nominated this for re-opening again, as this was the correct and easy-to-google answer for the question I needed.

Answer (score 24):

To get the URL of the current page as a string (no await needed):

```
page.url()
```

Where "page" is an object of the Page class.  You should already have a Page object, and there are various ways to instantiate it, depending on how your framework is set up: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page

It can be imported with

```
import Page from '@playwright/test';
```

or this

```
const { webkit } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await webkit.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
}
```

Comment: In many cases, `await expect(page).toHaveURL(someURL)` may actually be what you're looking for.

Comment: In `dotnet/C#` I used `page.Url`. Hope to help someone.

Answer (score 19):

```js
const {browser}=this.helpers.Playwright;
await browser.pages(); //list pages in the browser

//get current page
const {page}=this.helpers.Playwright;
const url=await page.url();//get the url of the current page
```

Comment: `page.url()` is not a promise actually

Answer (score 0):

you can also use The `page.evaluate()` API

```
const href = await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
```

as mentioed in playwright documentation
[playwright evaluate API](https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating)

Answer (score 0):

To get and verify the current page URL using [toHaveURL](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-url):

```
await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*checkout/);
```