# Make certain Action on certain page with JS, Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

Im trying to do certain action on a certain page, but for some reason this action is active anyway, here is my code

```
if(URL = "certainPageUrl") {
  await this.button.click();
  await this.Inpt.clear();
  await this.Inpt.fill('text);
}
```

Any ideas on how get it work on a certain page?

Comment: comparison operator is `==`, single `=` does assignment

Comment: Yes, but if I use = it works always, if I use == it didnt works at all

Comment: if you use `=` it works always because the result of the assignment will be truthy from the `if` statement's perspective. inspect the actual value of `URL`, maybe simply does not contain the value you're expecting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current page url with Playwright Automation tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308751/get-current-page-url-with-playwright-automation-tool)

Comment: So I change on this

Comment: if(URL == "url") {
      await this.Btn.click();
      await this.Inpt.clear();
      await this.Inpt.fill(text);
      console.log(URL);
    }

Comment: I change Url from what I get from console.log, and use == but conditions still didnt works(

Comment: `=` is definitely a bug, so I'd [edit] your post to take care of that and use `===` (never `==`, which is unpredictable). If the code still doesn't work, then please provide a complete, runnable [mcve] with full Playwright code and the page you're automating, as well as a clear description of what you're trying to achieve, so we can begin to debug it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use === instead

```
let URL: string;
if(URL === "google.com") {
await this.button.click();
await this.Inpt.clear();
await this.Inpt.fill('text);
}
```

or use the switch statement:

```
switch (URL) {
    case "google.com":
        await this.button.click();
        await this.Inpt.clear();
        await this.Inpt.fill('text');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Not valid URL: '+ URL);
}
```

Comment: === didn't works for me also(, but its a good point. Thanks